# Show that the set S = {v1(1, 1), v2(1, -1)} is a basis for R2.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> 1. Let x = (x1, x2) represent an arbitrary vector in R2.  Consider the linear combination c1v1 + c2v2 = x,   (c1 + c2, c1-c2) = (x1, x2) 
>      c+c2 = x1 c-c2 = x2
>
> the coefficient matrix has a nonzero determinant, the system has a
>   unique solution. Therefore S spans R2.
>   2. S is linearly independent (verify it). Therefore S is a basis for R2.

This is the written solution but i am lost how the coefficient matrix has a non zero determinant?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the  determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: i know yes but determinant needs to be square matrix in order to calculate and dont we have 1x2 matrix ?